# RewriteRule not working do not know how to test it the regex matches

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache

Hello I have a Rewrite rule I am trying to implement on my local host but I cannot get it to  do the action no matter how I setup the regex

the files are in this naming scheme **/docroot/css/stylesheet.min.css** and I have them printed in the code like **/docroot/css/stylesheet.min.123438348.css** (the number is example it comes from a get modified function). Note docroot is an example directory

how can I have the server ignore the numbers and redirect to the stylesheet.min.css
I need to do this for every css and js files (/js and /css) as well as one specific spritemap image

my current attempt

```
RewriteRule ^/(docroot)/(js|css)/(.+)\.(min)\.(.+)\.(js|css)$ /$1/$2/$3.$4.$6
RewriteRule ^(/docroot/images/spritemap)\.([0-9]+)\.(png)$ $1.$3
```

I have this wrapped in a  I am on linux..should this be mod_rewrite.so?"

---

SO I am trying to setup a RewriteRule on my server for caching static objects. the files are in this naming scheme /docroot/css/stylesheet.min.css and I have them printed in the code like /docroot/css/stylesheet.min.123438348.css (the number is example it comes from a get modified function). Note docroot is an example directory

how can I have the server ignore the numbers and redirect to the stylesheet.min.css I need to do this for every css and js files (/js and /css) as well as one specific spritemap image

my current attempt

```
RewriteRule ^/(docroot)/(js|css)/(.+).(min).(.+).(js|css)$ /$1/$2/$3.$4.$6 
RewriteRule ^(/docroot/images/spritemap).([0-9]+).(png)$ $1.$3
```

Update: Now I have the setup like this

```
<Location />
RewriteEngine on
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(min)\.([0-9]+)\.(js|css)$ $1.$2.$4 [L]
</Location>
```

This is rewriting localhost/docroot/css/stylesheet.min.12343242.css to /var/www/html/docroot/trunk/docroot/css/stylesheet.min.css

so it is getting the right file how do I get apache to take off the beginning of the that the /var/www/html/docroot/trunk/

```
<Location />
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(min)\.([0-9]+)\.(js|css)$ $1.$2.$4 [PT]
</Location>
```

Options FollowSymLinks in Directory listing

Ok Now instead of

```
/var/www/html/docroot/trunk/docroot/css/stylesheet.min.css
```

I am getting a url that looks like this

```
/docroot/trunk/docroot/css/stylesheet.min.css
```

I Removed the RewriteBase command so I still need to remove the beginning /docroot/trunk

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine on` somewhere (e.g., `.htaccess`)?

Comment: yea the rewrite works now it just is not producing the desired url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern of rules for [per-directory rewrites](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) differs from those for a global rewrites:

> - When using the rewrite engine in .htaccess files the per-directory prefix (which always is the same for a specific directory) is automatically *removed* for the `RewriteRule` pattern matching and automatically *added* after any relative (not starting with a slash or protocol name) substitution encounters the end of a rule set. See the `RewriteBase` directive for more information regarding what prefix will be added back to relative substutions.
> - The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, A *Pattern* with `^/` never matches in per-directory context.

So try these patterns without the leading prefix `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^(docroot)/(js|css)/(.+)\.(min)\.(.+)\.(js|css)$ /$1/$2/$3.$4.$6
RewriteRule ^(docroot/images/spritemap)\.([0-9]+)\.(png)$ $1.$3
```